# Menu entry in toctree expands/collapses on click and doesn't change page content?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, expandable, toctree

As per the title, is it possible to have a menu entry where the entire entry acts like the +/- for expanding and collapsing and doesn't change the active page?

A bit like when you are already on the actual entry and click it again it only expands/collapses.

index.rst

```
Introduction
============
Some introductory text here

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   self
   srg/index
```

srg/index.rst

```
srg
===
Normal menu entry that shows this as its page

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   objects/index
```

srg/objects/index.rst

```
Objects
=======
I don't want this to be a page but only an expand/collapse entry.

.. toctree ::
   :hidden:

   list
```

srg/objects/list.rst

```
list
====

Page content again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally dependent on the [Sphinx theme](https://sphinx-themes.org/) you use. If one does not support the feature you want out of the box, then you must modify the theme's JavaScript onclick behavior to your desire. Try [sphinx_rtd_theme](https://sphinx-themes.org/html/sphinx_rtd_theme/sphinx_rtd_theme/basic.html) or [sphinxbootstrap4theme](https://sphinx-themes.org/html/sphinxbootstrap4theme/sphinxbootstrap4theme/basic.html) to get something close or look into its documentation to see if there is a setting that does exactly what you want.